# Get list of all features in a specific scope (Active or Deactive)

Tags: powershell, feature

I want to get a list of all features in a specific scope using PowerShell. I want to get all activate and inactive features by providing the scope. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the next script

```
$allSiteFeatures = Get-SPFeature | Where-Object { $_.Scope -eq "Site" }
$activeFeatures = Get-SPFeature -Site "http://sitecollectionUrl"

$allSiteFeatures | ForEach-Object {
$active = $false
    foreach($feature in $activeFeatures)
    {
      if($feature.Id.ToString() -eq $_.Id.ToString())
      {
         $active = $true
      }
    }
    if(!$active)
    {
       $_.DisplayName
    }
}
```

Greetings